# Removing cursor from a doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, computer-science, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to remove the cursor from the list and make it reference to the previous CarListNode (or the head, if the cursor previously referenced the head of the list). While still returning the information inside the cursor.
My code doesn't correctly remove the cursor. What is the issue in my code?

Here is my current code:

```
public Fruit removeCursor() throws EndOfListException {

    if (cursor == null) {
        throw new EndOfListException();

    } else if (cursor.getPrev() == null) {
        head = cursor.getNext();
        cursor.setNext(null);
        cursor.setPrev(null);
        cursor = head;

    } else if (cursor.getNext() == null) {
        tail = cursor.getPrev();
        cursor.setPrev(null);
        cursor.setNext(null);
        cursor = tail;

    } else {
        cursor.setData(cursor.getNext().getData()); //this isn't a singly linked list
        cursor.setNext(cursor.getNext().getNext());
    }

    count--;

    return cursor.getData();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry late night. I was just asking what is wrong with my code because the cursor isn't being removed at intended.

Comment: *My code doesn't correctly remove the cursor. What is the issue in my code?* who knows what the cursor there is until you tell it,

Comment: I think you should use *node* instead or explain what do you mean by *cursor*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` clause does not "remove the cursor"...

Try something like this:

```
else {
    cursor.getPrev().setNext(cursor.getNext());
    cursor.getNext().setPrev(cursor.getPrev());
    // You might want to release the cursor's item, EG:
    cursor = null;
    cursor = cursor.getNext();
}
```